# How does Android know where to pick up?

Tags: android, crash

I have a bunch of Activities, basically initial user settings. So the user gets through the first screen, the second, the third, inputs all of his information, then let's say that the 6th Activity is the main app. But suppose that the main app crashes. When I relaunch the app, it starts off on say the 4th Activity, one of the login screens. How does Android store where to launch after a crash has occurred? How can I change this?

Comment: Not much you can do about that.  Once it crashes if you restart the app it should go back to whatever you declared as the main activity in your manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the basic:

> In android, every activity is stored in a stack like structure. Last in first out.
>
> Now if your app crashes in 6th activity , android will look for the last activity in the stack.

[image]

To change this, you have to add the appropriate flags with the intents that are used to call
your activities.

**EDIT:**

Also check this nice tutorial on intents with [code.](http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/)

Comment: Hmm can you give an example, or if you know of any good sources detailing how to do this?

Comment: this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) has everything you need... And dont forget to tick my answer if it helped you...